# Google sheet script to shift content once a day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to move the content of B2:F8 to C2:G8 (one column to the right) once a day, at 4am.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Move Stuff one column to the right

```
function movestuff() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter you sheetname");
  sh.getRange("B2:F8").moveTo(sh.getRange("C2:G8"));
}
```

Run the following function once to create the trigger

```
function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "moveStuff").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("moveStuff").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(4).create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run AppScript triggers to run your custom function once a Day.

For example, you have a function to do this content shifting in your Apps Script.

Then go to your **Triggers** > **Add Trigger** > Choose your function to run once in a day > Select the **Select event source** to **Time Driven** > Select type of time-based trigger to Day Timer

That's it. It will run a function once a day or you can customize your event whatever you like

From @Cooper solution you can take his code & call it in a daily based event timer.

```js
function contentShifter() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter you sheet tab name");
   sh.getRange("B2:F8").moveTo(sh.getRange("C2:G8"));
 }
```

Run the function **contentShifter** in daily event timer that's it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that. Any idea about shifting data one column to the right?

Comment: For that, you can find related questions in StackOverflow. If not I will give you an exact code in this answer.

Comment: Thanks! I would love to see your code for this.

Comment: You can follow @Cooper solution. It will also work
You can call that function from the event timer

I have updated the code. If it solves the problem of yours you can accept my answer, so It will help others